# Como faço para tirar uma parte específica de uma string em GOLANG

Tags: string, golang, split

Estou desenvolvendo um software e dentre as funcionalidades dele eu gostaria de separar uma parte específica de uma string

Meu código está assim até agora

```
baseURL := "https://google.com/" 
body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
localizaScript := string(body)
fmt.Println(localizaScript)

response.Body.Close()
```

Quando dou `fmt.Println(localizaScript)`, ele me retorna o HTML enorme da página em formato string, eu gostaria de pegar apenas a tag
`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.kabum.com.br/datadome.js"></script>`
e separar em uma outra variável string.

Comment: Qual o critério para realizar essa separação? **[Edite a sua pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/494509/edit)** para explicar melhor o algoritmo que você quer fazer. Também seria mais ideal tentar fornecer um código que você já tentou fazer. :-)

Comment: Pronto, acho que está melhor agora heheh

Comment: Você já pensou em utilizar uma biblioteca que analisa o HTML? Um exemplo é [`goquery`](https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery). Creio ser a melhor alternativa, até porque [expressões regulares não são ideias para _parsing_ de HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7445826).

Comment: Vou dar uma lida sobre :) obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que um Web Scraper resolva seu problema.

Experimente o `go get github.com/anaskhan96/soup` ou acesse https://github.com/anaskhan96/soup

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/anaskhan96/soup"
)

func main() {
    resp, err := soup.Get("http://g3n.rocks")
    if err != nil {
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    doc := soup.HTMLParse(resp)

    scripts := doc.FindAll("script")
    for _, script := range scripts {
        fmt.Println(script.Attrs()["src"])
        if script.Attrs()["src"] == "js/bootstrap.min.js" {
            fmt.Println("\n\n Achamos o bootstrap.min.js\n\n")
        }
    }
}
```

resultado:

```
https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-120217498-1

js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js     
js/popper.min.js
js/bootstrap.min.js        


 Achamos o bootstrap.min.js


js/mdb.min.js
```